# How to get the id of a dynamically created object in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

Edited the question for clarification.

In my Angular 8 Project, i have a **component1** that contains an array, and a button to create a new object to it. Then i have a **component2** that is the object beeing created. component2 holds a button itself, that should redirect the user to a **component3**, by adding the id of the created component 2 object to the url, like `localhost/component3/id1` .

In Component 2, im getting a click input to trigger an update to the array via a button that listens for the following method

```
public onSelect() {

    const eventObject: EventPing = {
      label:'id',
      object: this.component2Data
    };
    this.ping.emit(eventObject)
  }
```

component2Data comes into component2 via  `@Input() component2Data:`
from component1 and has a standard value of `id:undefined, position:undefined`. The variable **ping** exits component2 via   `@Output() ping: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();`

in component1 HTML, the array looks like this:

```
 <app-component2 (ping)="update($event)" [component2Data]="component2new" *ngFor="let component2new of component2spawn"></app-component2>
```

so the array listens for a new **ping** and then releases a function. 
This function looks like this in component1 ts

```
public update(event: EventPing): void {
if ('id' === event.label) {
      this.router.navigate(['/component3', event.object.id]);
    }
  }
```

this function should direct the user to component3, with the objects id attached. To make this work, the app router is set to `path: 'workarea/:id',`
and component 3 has activatedroute in the constructor.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {  }
```

what now happens onclick is the error `The requested path contains undefined segment at index 1"` and every time i console.log the event.object.id i get id undefined for all objects.

the interesting part is that **when i use `event.object.position`, it works** and i get redirected to localhost/component3/1  (or whatever position it is)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the object id as an argument of the `onSelect` method and get it from the template assuming that you're looping over the array (some template code would've been helpful if you posted it):

```
public onSelect(id: string) {
    this.router.navigate(['component2', id]);
  }
```

In your template file (I just assume that you have something similar since you haven't post it to much data):

```
<div *ngFor="let object of myObjects">
  ...
  <button (click)="onSelect(object.id)>Select</button>
</div>
```

In your routing configuration:

```
{
 path: 'component2/:id', // ':' tells Angular that is a dynamic parameter
 compomnent: Component2
}
```

Comment: object.id does not work in my context. forgot to mention the object and the array are in different components. The objects array looks like this `<app-objects  [object]="objectnew" *ngFor="let objectnew of objectspawn"></app-objects>`

then in the object component i have `@Input() object: objecttype;`
by default, a newly created object gets these values: 

   ` this.object = {
                id: undefined,
                position: undefined
    
            };`

Comment: @DuBloxx can you edit your question with this info. It will be more visible that way. And if you can create a minimal representation in stackblitz it will be even easier for us to help you.